# Why do rain droplets differ so "much" in size?

Tags: condensed-matter, meteorology

Why do rain droplets differ so "much" in size? From the ones in drizzle rain to the droplets in a heavy shower?

I guess there is a complicated interplay between the height from which they fall, the humidity, the wind speed, friction and things I've overlooked.

If the air is *very* humid (coming straight from a warm ocean) after which the air enters land, above which the air is much colder (which can contain less water vapour), I can imagine that big drops condensate (of course they start out small but increase in size fast due to condensation), because of the big difference in humidity and temperature. When the fall down (for a great part by condensation), they can even get bigger by merging with other drops, or breaking up if they become too big. The wind plays obviously a role here. It lets drops collide with each other, which makes them smaller. But this effect is less if the drops are heavier.

On the other side of the size spectrum, we have drizzle rain. These drops stay little, meaning they haven't merged too much with other drops. It's like their distances to each other don't grow that much. I guess they don't originate at a great height, and the wind keeps their mean distance to each other more or less the same (in contrast with the big drops, which have a relatively greater difference in size).

Middle-class drops, which fall mostly during long periods of rainfall (except maybe in the monsoon rains), are an in-between case.

These are my own thoughts, but I'm sure there are people who know more about this.

Comment: A lot of different factors can affect the size of a raindrop. Factors such as temperature and windspeed are one of the biggest influences on the size of raindrops

Comment: What is the intended function of the quote marks around the word "much" in the title and body of this question?

Comment: Are you trying to use quotation marks for emphasis? Quotation marks do not indicate emphasis.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Try googling your title.

Comment: @user2357112-I didn't use the quotation marks for emphasis.

Comment: @sammygerbil-You can find an answer to all the questions asked here by other means than this forum.

Comment: There is really no call for the use of quotation marks here.

Answer (score 20):

The size of a rain drop depends on the process of formation. In principle, condensation of moist air at high altitudes causes tiny drops to form. As soon as those drops get big enough, they start to fall. Now if these drops encounter other little drops on their way down (big drops fall faster, so they catch up with little drops), they will "eat" the little drops and get even bigger. They will keep doing this until they reach the ground.

At the same time, when a drop gets sufficiently large, it will deform and can "explode" back into a bunch of smaller drops. An interesting article including a slow-motion video of this process can be seen [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17487-myth-of-raindrop-formation-exploded/)

Turbulence in the air plays an important role in this formation process. When the air "changes direction" a lot, smaller droplets tend to be dragged along with it - while larger drops have greater inertia compared to their drag. This means that under turbulent conditions, smaller drops will slam into bigger drops (where under calm conditions the big drops go faster and "eat" the little drops).

The result is that for a given moisture content in the air, and altitude / thickness of the clouds, you will get a certain size of rain drops. The thicker/denser the clouds, the more drops from the top can grow and absorb moisture in lower layers. And when there is more wind, it also increases the drop size as explained by the turbulence argument.

A lecture exploring this in more detail can be found [here](http://www.nsstc.uah.edu/mips/personnel/kevin/thermo/chap8-raindrops-ver5Nov09.pdf) - see especially slide 7 and further.

Comment: Then, could this be used to measure height of clouds by size of droplets?  Is something like that doen?

Comment: Does drizzle rain originate at low altitudes? I mean, is drizzle rain accompanied by mist and low wind speed? Drizzle rain drops also encounter other drizzle rain drops.

Comment: @descheleschilder - either low altitude, or low cloud thickness. In other words - from the point where rain is generated, it doesn't pass through a lot of other droplets. Incidentally - once you get past a certain size, big rain drops can become unstable and "explode" into smaller drops again. See for example [this article](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17487-myth-of-raindrop-formation-exploded/) and the associated video.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to point out that (like lots of physics) the making of raindrops gets more complicated, but more beautiful, the more you look at it. For example, it's easier to start raindrops in "dirty" air, so they are often smaller, rather like how adding sugar to soda can mean it makes a load of small bubbles.

Comment: I'm wary of obvious-sounding answers on a question like this one. Could you beef it up with some appropriate references?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty fair point I added a link to a comprehensive lecture on the topic - including terminal velocities, drop formation, shape, probability of collision, etc.

Comment: +1 One important mechanism has been left out, viz. collisions between droplets due to their interaction with turbulence, when the droplets are small enough that settling under gravity may be ignored. Also the statement "The thicker the clouds, the more drops from the top can grow and absorb moisture in lower layers" is incorrect, because condensational growth plays an important role only during initial stages of droplet growth (up to $\sim 40~\mu m$), after which collision and coalescence is the major contributor to growth. See _A short course in Cloud Physics_ by Rogers & Yau.

Comment: I found this article: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/qj.49707632704/abstract

Comment: @Deep thank you for your comment. I incorporated a bit about turbulence in my answer. Will have to try to locate a copy of Rogers and Yau.

Answer (score 8):

According to a [French researcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsWaqdL_Y2I), raindrops differ in size because of [topological changes](http://www.livescience.com/7809-raindrops-fall-sizes.html) they undergo as they fall.  They start out spherical when they first form within clouds.  Surface tension maintains that shape.  However, as they fall and encounter air resistance they flatten like a pancake, and then air pressure pushes up the center and they become umbrella-like.  As air pressure builds inside the inverted cup shape of the falling raindrop, eventually it explodes into a chaotic shower of smaller drops of various sizes.

Mist rising from near ground level is very fine and uniform compared to raindrops, as mist droplets do not fall from a great enough height to undergo topological change.  Similarly, the super-large raindrops that fall in the still air that precedes some thunderstorms, form from warm moist air drawn from ground level into low-lying clouds prior to the violent downpour of chaotic droplet sizes that follows the advancing weather front.

Comment: @Ernie-Doesn't the raindrop take the form in which it has the least air resistance?

Comment: Raindrops will flatten. There is a nice slow motion video online... https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17487-myth-of-raindrop-formation-exploded/

Comment: @descheleschilder : As a raindrop falls, its wake creates lower air pressure on top of the raindrop, which draws up the top into a cup shape.  At first, faster air across the bottom creates pressure that flattens the center, but then airflow accelerates on top, which expands the top into a cup shape, which explodes.  Take a look at the video link in Floris' comment.  Air pressure flattens the drop, draws water away from the bottom center, and draws up the top center.  Then, air on top accelerates, and the pressure difference explodes the drop.  The same principle shapes a sail on a boat.

Comment: @descheleschilder : The reason airflow above the drop accelerates as the drop forms a cup shape, is that air must flow across a greater distance outside the cup's curve than air the inside the cup's curve.  Likewise, the sail of a boat forms a concave shape because the leeward side of the cupped sail forces air to go a greater distance during the same time that air flows across the windward inside of the sail.  If the sail were not strong, it would expand and explode like a raindrop.